# NiFI registry encrypt-config.sh does not encrypt the providers.xml "Remote Access Password"

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I use the git for FlowPersistenceProvider for nifi registry. But encrypt tool does not support encryptyng the file providers.xml. providers.xml contains the parameter "Remote Access Password" for connacting to my git repositry.

Are there any ways to encrypt this parameter "Remote Access Password" in providers.xml?